# Is it possible to block access to email when using shared e-mail box in outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

is it possible to block access to e-mail that is being read/open by one user while using Outlook shared e-mail box (obviously- block access for other users of shared e-mail box)? If yes- is it a built-in option or I need a plug-in or VBA macro? When I try to google it I end up with hundreds of manuals that show how to block receiving mails from addresses but I cannot find solution to my problem.

Big thanks to anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Outlook/MAPI object can be locked.

Comment: is it possible to notify other user that somebody else is working with this particular message?

Comment: No. But you are free to change a property to make it clear to the other user that the item must be left alone , e.g. prefix its subject with "Locked". That of course would change  the last modification date and possibly other properties, sich as its conversation properties.